# Can WinAppDriver work with desktop applications that aren't windows native?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, ui-automation, winappdriver

I'm looking into automation testing for an AutoCAD-like program for desktops. I went through a tutorial and got a script working for the calculator app, but I'm unable to find & locate elements in other applications that aren't native to Windows 10. Is this possible & it's potentially an issue with how I'm locating elements or will it just not work at all? If so, is there any similar solution for desktop apps that use selenium?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.